# Сложное условие в Excel (ЕСЛИ)

Tags: excel

Добрый день! Прошу помочь с написанием формулы в EXСEL  под следующие условия:
Если значение ячейки меньше 3000, то в ней необходимо указать 3000. Если больше, то оставить указанное в ячейке значение. Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 1):

Допустим, ваша колонка N.

Создаете рядом новую колонку.
Пишете

```
=IF(N1>3000,N1,3000)
```

или

```
=ЕСЛИ(N1>3000,N1,3000)
```

Далее копируете ЗНАЧЕНИЯ, переносите в оригинальную колонку, удаляете временную.

P.S. Лично мне неизвестен способ, кроме написания VB скрипта, как поменять значение в той же самой ячейке, одновременно записав туда и данные, и формулу.

Comment: Спасибо, т.к. надо было срочно, я "косметическим" способом скрыл исходный столбец (в Вашем примере "N"). Ваш ответ мне очень помог.

Comment: @Vintare, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
 =МАКС(значение;3000)
```

Естественно, не в той же ячейке. Как перенести, описал в своем ответе *knes*

Comment: Значение в ячейке вычисляется, а не вводится, угадал? Если да, то вместо "значение" подставляется формула, по которой вычисляется значение ячейки.

Comment: Константа, ссылка на ячейку, формула - без разницы. Автор спрашивал о замене значений:  =МАКС(A1;3000) Потом заменить формулу значениями. заменить исходные данные полученными.

Comment: Разница есть, так как если там формула, то не понадобятся действия, предложенные knes'ом.

Comment: Да, если не МЕНЯТЬ, а ПОЛУЧАТЬ значение